# C# How to rename current file name after closing the application

Tags: c#, visual-studio

im coding on c#, im trying to make when the application closing the name of the file will be changed.

my base name in the application changing every 10ticks in timer random strings and i want it to take the last string and change the main name to that string.

for example:
the application closed and the last string in the application is xxx2345 then changing the filename to xxx2345.exe

so im looking for rename filename after closing.

Comment: Are you coding a malware?

Comment: no, just something that im trying to make

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between ***after*** closing and ***when (while) *** closing the application. I am assuming you want to do the second.

There are few options. One way will be to copy the exe file with a new name.Then 
1. Delete the old file via shell command / windows scheduler (say 1 min in future) or
2. when the new file is opened, it deletes the older version (you will need a set formula for file names between version, or a registry / local storage for previous name)

Comment: yes, that what im looking for, can you help me to code this?

Comment: @AnonyMM I'd recommend giving a try at the implementation and show the attempt if you have any specific issue. Just asking for general coding tutoring is not fit for the "one question - unique answers" Q&A like Stack Overflow, the question may not be well received as such.

Comment: Sorry - my C# programming skill is not great. I was commenting on a solution approach. Renaming and deleting files should not be that difficult in any language incl. C#.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, you want to rename current file name after closing the application.

You could try the following code to get it.

```
        string str = r.Next(1000).ToString();
        string str1 = Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.ModuleName;     
        Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName(str1);
        if (ps.Length <= 0)
        {
            string filePath = System.Environment.CurrentDirectory; ;            
            string newFileName = filePath + "\\" + str + ".exe";                 
            File.Move(str1, newFileName);
        }
```

This is my tested result:

[image]